# Php : Logical query with some complications

Tags: php, html

I have basic knowledge to write codes in php but I'm stucked in logical process. Hope I can get some help here.

**Problem :**

I want to compare and declare winner between 2 workers based on performance. Details are given below :

```
$working_first = 2;
$available_canches = 5;
$target_minutes = 40;
```

Details of Worker1

```
$worker1 = 2 ;
$worker1_chances_taken = 4;
$worker1_points = 80;
$worker1_minutes = 40;
```

Details of Worker2

```
$worker2 = 5 ;
$worker2_chances_taken = 5;
$worker2_points = 95;
$worker2_minutes = 35;
```

Expected Solution:

I want to run some process...

- `if $working_first == $worker1 AND $target_minutes>$worker1_minutes OR $available_chances>$worker1_chances_taken`
- OR
- `if $working_first != $worker1 AND $worker1_points>$worker2_points AND $target_minutes>$worker2_minutes OR $available_chances>$worker2_chances_taken`

Syntax I'm Using For Output:

```
if (($working_first==$worker1 && ($target_minutes>$worker1_minutes || $available_chances>$worker1_chances_taken)) || ($working_first != $worker1 && $worker1_points>$worker2_points && ($target_minutes>$worker2_minutes || $available_chances>$worker2_chances_taken)) {

echo 'Process Continues';

}

else {

echo 'Process Ends';

}
```

I'm unable to get desired output.

Please help me to get it.

Thanks.

Comment: well, how should it work? You first if() test fails because `$working_first` is 2, so it can't be `worker1`. The second `if()` fails because worker1's points are LESS than worker2's points, so the only possible solution is to hit the `else` clause.

Comment: I think you're missing a `)` right before `{`

Comment: Hmmm bro...Woker1 and worker2 are two workers of the company and company decides to organise between these two worker but gives first chance to worker1 to score points. but for that he has limited sources (chances and mints.) if he match given source targets than he should not able to perform his duties and worker2 has to chase down points worker1 scored....

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the brackets correctly. Try with this:

```
if (
 (
  $working_first == $worker1
  && 
  (
   $target_minutes > $worker1_minutes 
   || 
   $available_chances > $worker1_chances_taken
  )
 ) 
 || 
 (
  $working_first != $worker1 
  && 
  $worker1_points > $worker2_points 
  && 
  (
   $target_minutes > $worker2_minutes 
   || 
   $available_chances > $worker2_chances_taken
  )
 )
) {

 echo 'Process Continues';

} else {

 echo 'Process Ends';

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use it in production. :-)

Comment: Still not working bro ....process keeps running even if worker1_minutes are greater than target minutes..:(

Comment: I'm not surprised, because you said that _$working_first = 2_. This means that _$worker1_minutes_ is not relevant, because the if condition jumps to the second subcondition (the half starting with _$working_first != $worker1_). I guess you wrote your condition wrong. Split it and proceed slowly.